# Query about distribution certificate and development certificate in iOS app distribution

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, ios4, ios-simulator

i want to know do we need both `distribution certificate` and `development certificate`, if i want to give my app to any one else or want to install on other mobile?

how can i setup my code signing with this certificates in `xcode`?

can anyone give me a screenshot for it?

Answer (score 0):

1. First you want to register with the Apple Developer Program (99$).
2. After that you want add your Device UDID.
3. Then you create the developer and distribution certificates.
4. Download these certificates and install them into your system.
5. Now In your Xcode Build Settings Set the Corresponding profile.
6. Connect your device and run it.

Comment: Suresh read the question before answering. He already has a profile and he already knows about the steps.

Answer (score 0):

The development and distribution is both necessary. They are both used in archiving which is a step you take when you want to upload your app to App Store. If you want to allow your friend to have the app you developed on their device, just connect the device in xcode and click on use for development. Then you can upload your app to their device for testing. You can register up to 99 devices to your development id. If you decide to publish your app on the App Store then you need to go through the steps of uploading your app and then you need your distribution profile. I hope this answer your question.